# How to implement generic query using GraphQL/HotChocolate in C#

Tags: asp.net-core, generics, graphql, hotchocolate

We have multiple `classes/entities` and wants to implement `single query` for all these types. Basically we want to implement a `Query` something like this.

```
public class Query<TEntity> 
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<TEntity> _genericRepository;

        public Query(IGenericRepository<TEntity> genericRepository)
        {
            _genericRepository = genericRepository;
        }
        public List<TEntity> GetCountries()
        {
            return _genericRepository.GetAll();
        }
    }
```

Can you please give any hint or reference for the similar problem?

Comment: AFAIK the closest you can do is to provide an enum as input and a union as output. Every time you want to add support for a new `TEntity` you will have to extend the enum and union.